# При уменьшении экрана контейнер прижимается к левому краю

Tags: html, css, flexbox

При обычном экране блоки по центру с равным расстоянием, но при уменьшении жмутся к левому краю

```css
#works{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #fbfaf8;
  margin-top: 100px
}
.portfolio{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.portfolio ul,
.portfolio li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.portfolio li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio img{
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.descr{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
  padding-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition:  all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.portfolio li:hover .descr{
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="works">
      <h1>Примеры работ</h1>
      <div class="portfolio">
        <ul>
          <li><span class="descr">Описание</span><img src="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2005/Animals_Cats__001795_1.jpg" alt="alt"></li>
          <li><span class="descr">Описание</span><img src="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2005/Animals_Cats__001795_1.jpg" alt="alt"></li>
          <li><span class="descr">Описание</span><img src="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2005/Animals_Cats__001795_1.jpg" alt="alt"></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Comment: В этом редакторе не видно этого(

Comment: Естественно "жмутся", вы же указали для них фиксированную ширину, вот они и сдвигаются, когда места под них не хватает. Как в идеале должны вести себя блоки при более мелком разрешении?

Comment: Располагаться в центре и идти вертикально

Answer (score 1):

У вас куча стандартных стилей браузеров применяется к спискам, заголовкам и подобным элементам, поэтому такое не корректное поведение. Вот и проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обычно лучше сбросить стандартные стили, например с помощью ResetCSS. Почитать подробнее можно [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/45296/).

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
#works{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #fbfaf8;
  margin-top: 100px
}
.portfolio{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.portfolio ul,
.portfolio li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.portfolio li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio img{
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.descr{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
  padding-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition:  all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.portfolio li:hover .descr{
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="works">
      <h1>Примеры работ</h1>
      <div class="portfolio">
        <ul>
          <li><span class="descr">Описание</span><img src="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2005/Animals_Cats__001795_1.jpg" alt="alt"></li>
          <li><span class="descr">Описание</span><img src="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2005/Animals_Cats__001795_1.jpg" alt="alt"></li>
          <li><span class="descr">Описание</span><img src="http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/1366x768/2005/Animals_Cats__001795_1.jpg" alt="alt"></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Comment: при уменьшении станицы блоки не встают вертикально по центру - нужно боковые маргины auto  к #works добавить , или что-то в этом роде